# Is there a mistake in this uniform convergence problem?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} = a$ if and only if the succession of functions $f_n(x) = f(x+n)$ converge uniformly in $[0, + \infty)$ for the constant function $a$.

I think there is a mistake cause if I take the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$ its limit is 0 as x goes to infinity but clearly the functions $f_n$ doesn't converges uniformly in $[0, +\infty)$ because $f$ is not continuous in the point $x=1$. However i can say $f_n(x) = f(x+n)$ converges uniformly in the interval $(1, +\infty)$. Am'I right or i'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is correct. In fact, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{f(x)} = a$ iff for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$ for all $x\geq n$, that is iff 
$$\epsilon>\sup_{x\in [n,+\infty)}|f(x)-a|=\sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|f(x+n)-a|=\sup_{x\in [0,+\infty)}|f_n(x)-a|$$ 
which means that $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $[0,+\infty)$ to the constant function $a$,

Note that in your example, $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in the interval $[0,+\infty)$. In fact,as $n\to+\infty$,
$$\sup_{x\in[0,+\infty)}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\sup_{x\in[0,+\infty)}\left|\frac{1}{x+n-1}\right|=\sup_{x\in[n-1,+\infty)}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{n-1}\to 0.$$